# Using Genius API

Tags: python, python-requests

The docs are here: https://docs.genius.com/

I'm new to using APIs and I've been trying to figure out how to use this with no luck. I have the client id, secret id, and access token already.

What I'm trying to do is:

- get artist id
- get all the songs by an artist
- get the lyrics to a song

I have this working right now - input artist name and a song and it will return [data](https://pastebin.com/iKtexJ4a). Now how would I go through that data - like how would I get the 'full_title', 'id', or the lyrics?

```
#search for song
import requests

client_access_token = ''
base_url = 'https://api.genius.com'

user_input = input('artist and song: ').replace(" ", "-")

path = 'search/'
request_uri = '/'.join([base_url, path])
print(request_uri + user_input)

params = {'q': user_input}

token = 'Bearer {}'.format(client_access_token)
headers = {'Authorization': token}

r = requests.get(request_uri, params=params, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're pretty close. I just took a quick look, but bet you need something like this.

```
import requests

payload={
'genius_client_id' : '',
'genius_secret_id' : '',
'genius_client_access_token' : ''}

base_url = 'https://api.genius.com/'

r = requests.get(base_url, params=payload)
print(r.status_code) #200 is good
```

P.S. the requests docs are very helpful, might take a look there too

Comment: hmmm, I'm getting 403.

Comment: That's the "Forbidden" status. I'd guess that the request isn't complete, like you need some more parameters. You should be able to add them to the payload dict.

Comment: What other parameters? Like I tried adding redirect uri, scope, state, response type - and I'm still getting 403. I don't know if I'm putting them in wrong or what.

Answer (score -1):

You are pretty close to getting the details of the songs(lyrics, id,etc..). All you have to do is go through the JSON element. The JSON file contains information about your search.
In this case, the file will contain data about many songs that appear in the search but I will show how to navigate to the lyrics of the first song.

```
#this gives the link for the lyrics page of the searched song.
#This is for the first result of the search. You can use a for loop if you want the URL for more results.

URL = json['response']['hits'][0]['result']['url']
print(URL)

#to get the lyrics out of the page I used beautifulsoup in the following way.
page = requests.get(url)
html = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
lyrics = html.find('div', class_='lyrics').get_text()
lyrics = re.sub(r'[\(\[].*?[\)\]]', '', lyrics)
print(lyrics)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Scraping websites is ugly and obnoxious. Considerate users will attempt to gain the publisher's permission to sic bots on a website, or else use a proper API that returns desired fields in JSON or XML format.